# Trying to nest objects inside of arrays for a PHP card game, to later reference the members

Tags: php

I a working on a card game written in PHP. I have created a class for each card and I have created a class for the deck that will hold the cards. Here is a snippet of my logic:

```
class Card{
    private $width;
    private $height;
    private $value;
    private $suit;
    private $face;

    function __contruct($suit, $face, $width,$height, $value)
    {
      $this->suit = $suit;
      $this->face = $face;
      $this->width = $width;
      $this->height = $height;
      $this->value = $value;
    }    
}

class Deck{
    private $deck = array();
    private $suits = array ("Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds");
    private $value = array(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14);
    private $faces = array (
    "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight",
    "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"
 );
public function __construct()
    {
       $i = 0;
        foreach ($this->suits as $suit[]) 
        {            
            $width -= 73;
            foreach($this->faces as $face) 
            {
            $height -= 98;  
            //['face'] . ' of ' . $card['suit'];
            $this->deck[] = new Card($suit, $face, $width, $height, $value);
        }
    }
    public function getDeck()
    {
     return $this->deck;
    }


 }
```

In a driver program I would like to reference members inside the card class.
For example: suit, face, value etc

This is what I have tried
    $deck = new Deck();
    $cards = var_dump($deck->getDeck());
    //me attempting to reference member of card class
    $cards[0]->suit;

I am using an object oriented approach to this for the sake of learning.

When I am using the var_dump listed above I get null values instead of the value of the members from the card class. This is not what I expected; I expected to values such as hearts, diamonds etc.

Comment: `__construct` is misspelled in the `Card` class

Comment: `foreach ($this->suits as $suit[])` is incorrect. It should be just `$suit`. `[]` is syntactical sugar and is the equivalent of `array_push()`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I made the corrections as suggested and my code is now working.